# Best way to reference an entity type as a field on another entity in Symfony2 and Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

In my SF2/Doctrine2 application i have a entity "User", then another abstract parent entity (which I'll call plant for simplicity's sake) with two subtypes (tree and bush). What I want is for the user to be able to configure which plant subtype they are going to use, then any time they create a new Plant it creates one of this subtype, tree or bush.

My discriminator column looks like this on plant:

```
 /**
   * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
   * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="integer")
   * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
   *   0 = "Tree",
   *   1 = "Bush"
   * })
   */
```

My question is how best to create a field on the user entity to select the entity type the User wants to reference. The best I can come up with is something like:

```
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="plantType", type="integer")
   */
  protected $plantType;
```

Then needing to duplicate this data in another function somewhere on the User class:

```
public function createNewPlant(){
  if ($this->plantType == 0) return new Tree();
  elseif ($this->plantType == 1) return new Bush();
}
```

This seems wrong to me since I'm mapping the integer value to the plant type in two places. Is there a better method?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You may be better off creating a ManyToMany between User and Plant.  Bush and Tree entities are assumed to exist and be properly defined. Then in User you could create a `new Tree()` or `new Bush()`.  The Plant entity would contain properties and methods shared by trees & bushes and be available to either new tree or bush entities.

Comment: Correction: User should have ManyToMany with Bush & with Tree, not Plant.  Plant, in most ways, becomes "invisible".